# Вывод дочерних страниц

Tags: html, cms, modx

Есть сайт на MODx Revo.

Структура каталога такая

1. Главная страница
2. Про нас
3. Новости
   и т.д.

Также есть шаблоны, которые выводят содержимое.

Надо сделать страницы, которые по логике являются дочерними элементами страницы Про нас.

Как правильно их создать? Создавать отдельный ресурс для каждой страницы и показывать используя шаблон, или есть какой то более изящный способ это сделать?

Comment: что означает ваше: "по логике являются дочерними элементами"? Создайте дочерние документы, какие требуется и где требуется. И выводите к примеру средствами [pdoResources](http://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources). Уточните, что Вы именно имеете в виду.

Comment: http://dev.ananas.net.ua/portfolio.html

Comment: Вот например страница, как правильно вывести все страницы из этого раздела, не создавая для каждой из них отдельного ресурса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведённом Вами примере принцип примерно такой:

Структура -

```
1. Главная
2. Портфолио
  2.1 Первая работа
  2.2 Вторая работа
  2.3 Третья работа
  ...
...
```

Каждая работа явлется дочерним рессурсом Портфолио. Вывести все работы, которые имеются можно примерно таким образом:

```
[[pdoResources?
 &tpl=`ListRowTpl`
]]
```

Где чанк `ListRowTpl` - это разметка элемента списка всех работ. Например:

```
<li><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a></li>
```

Если требутся вывести все работы, но не на странице Портфолио, а в любом другом месте, то стоит добавить параметр `&parents`. Значением которого будет id раздела Портфолио.

```
[[pdoResources?
    &parents=`1` // id Портфолио
    &tpl=`ListRowTpl`
]]
```

Если же требуется выводить не дочерние элементы, а просто определённый список ресурсов, то требуется воспользоваться параметром `&resources`, а также поставить `&parents` в значение `0`

```
[[pdoResources?
    &tpl=`ListRowTpl`
    &parents=`0`
    &resources=`4,5,245` // список с id нужных ресурсов
]]
```

Также не забывайте про документацию [pdoResources](http://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources). Там имеется описание всех имеющихся параметров, которые могут Вам пригодиться.

**upd:** Предварительно конечно надо установить `pdoResources` и комментарии, которые я указывал в примерах вызова также требуется удалить.

Comment: А если надо вывести не список работ, а конкретную страницу портфолио?

Comment: @wkornilow в `&resources` указать id нужной страницы

Comment: Если просто требуется вывести к примеру содержимое другого ресурса, то можно воспользоваться [pdoField](http://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdofield)

Comment: То есть, если у меня есть 20 работ, т.е. 20 страниц, мне для каждой надо создать 20 часов, и уже используя pdoResources выводить где надо?

Comment: @wkornilow "часов" видимо имелось в виду "чанков"? Чанка достаточно одного, если внешний вид выводимых ресурсов будет одинаковый.

Comment: Да, чанков:). По сути структура одинаковая, но содержимое разное. Если хватает одного чанка, то где задавать то,  что надо отображать?

Comment: @wkornilow Именно в чанке. В ответе приведён пример. (`[[+pagetitle]]`- заголовок) Если например требуется ещё содержимое то это `[[+content]]` итд.

Comment: То есть чанк будет один, но будет 20 ресурсов, я правильно понял?

Comment: Именно. Не стоит превращать комментарии в чат. Пробуйте, на деле всё станет гораздо понятней.